# Why this code can't POST anything using Rest API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, arraylist

Do you see why this code doesn't work? I can't add any topic to my list through function addTopic (I get a error message attached at the end).

```
private List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Topic("java", "back", "java description"),
            new Topic("html", "front", "html description"),
            ));

public void addTopic(Topic topic) {
    topics.add(topic);
}   

@PostMapping("/topics")
public void addTopic(@RequestBody Topic topic) {
    topicService.addTopic(topic);
}

public class Topic {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public Topic(String id, String name, String description) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",

Comment: The code above has nothing to do with the error message. Who calls your resource with what request? Where is the rest of the `Topic` class? Why do you have no minimal runnable example and just random snippets of code?

Comment: I use Postman app to do POST and GET requests, I use Content-Type application/json, I have added the rest of Topic class in the code

Comment: Don't put code in comments but edit your question, otherwise it will be closed sooner or later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@PostMapping(path = "/***", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public void addTopic(@RequestBody Topic topic) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped, now I don't get an error, but I still can't post anything, maybe it is not, because of the code and problem is somewhere else